# Sorting layers in legend using python in QGIS 2.4

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, qgis-2.4

In QGIS 2.2 , I was able to sort in alphabetical order the layers simply using this:

```
self.maplegendtree = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QTreeWidget, "theMapLegend")
self.maplegendtree.sortItems(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

I search a lot and I understand there where some changes with the legend in QGIS 2.4 ...

I tried this :

```
self.maplegendtree = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QTreeView, 'theLayerTreeView')
self.maplegendtree.setSortingEnabled(True);
self.maplegendtree.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder);
```

No error ... but no changes in the legend or mapcanvas?

Answer (score 1):

Following that super blog post
http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/
I will be able to sort manually my layers/groups using layerTreeRoot  and moving nodes at the right position.  Not as straight forward, but it should work.

Here a snippet  for moving one node (a group in this case)

```
self.treeRoot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot() 
lnGroup = self.treeRoot.findGroup("GroupName")
lnGroupClone = lnGroup.clone()
self.treeRoot.insertChildNode(1, lnGroupClone) #insert at index 1
self.treeRoot.removeChildNode(lnGroup)
```